# Using JSONSlurper to pass second level of JSON in list

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jsonslurper

I am using Groovy and JSON Slurper in one of my Jenkins plugins.
Below is the code I am using:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def inputFile = new File('.\\TestSuitesJ.json')
def inputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)
def keys = inputJSON.keySet() as List
```

This is how my test suite is defined:

```
{
  "Website1": {
  "smoke": "spec1.js",
  "default": "spec2.js"
  },
  "Website2": {
  "smoke": 
  ["spec1.js",
  "spec2.js",
  "spec3.js"],
  "default": 
  ["spec1.js",
  "spec5.js"],
  "TestSuite2":
  ["spec1.js"]
  }
}
```

Currently my list contains values as below if I use above code:

> Website1 Website2

However I want it to contain value as below if : select `Website2`:

> smoke default Testsuite2

Can someone please suggest a way? I tried below code but it is not working:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def inputFile = new File('.\\TestSuitesJ.json')
def inputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)
def keys = inputJSON.keySet('Website2') as List
```

Comment: There's no such key: `registry`.

Comment: I want to fetch values inside registry tag of my json `smoke default Testsuite2`. I am new to groovy so I am not sure how to achieve this. I also tried `def keys = inputJSON.keySet().registry as List` but that is also not working.

Comment: Ok, but there's no such key `registry` in the JSON you're parsing.

Comment: My Bad. I corrected it. I want Website2 and not registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{
  "Website1": {
     "smoke": "spec1.js",
     "default": "spec2.js"
  },
  "Website2": {
     "smoke": 
        ["spec1.js",
         "spec2.js",
         "spec3.js"],
     "default": 
        ["spec1.js",
         "spec5.js"],
      "TestSuite2":
        ["spec1.js"]
    }
}'''

def inputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)
def keys = inputJSON.Website2.keySet()
```